# mySQL CONCAT_WS one database to another

Tags: mysql

I am trying to append some database information from an old database to a new one. Below is the code i am using however i get the following error and don't know why.

```
UPDATE specs s, cross_ref c 
SET s.cross_ref = CONCAT_WS(',', 's.cross_ref', 'c.comp_num) 
WHERE s.part_num = c.part_num
```

Error:

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''c.comp_num) 
WHERE s.part_num = c.part_num' at line 1"
```

Comment: Remove the quotes around `s.cross_ref` and `c.comp_num`.  `CONCAT_WS(',', s.cross_ref, c.comp_num)`  Those are column names, which should not be single-quoted.

Comment: Use an editor with synxtax highlighting :)

Comment: I guess I had a bad case of the the Mondays... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your single quotes are in the wrong place - you don't need to wrap the column names.

```
UPDATE specs s, cross_ref c 
SET s.cross_ref = CONCAT_WS(',', s.cross_ref, c.comp_num) 
WHERE s.part_num = c.part_num
```